# Remove white squares around text in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

Under IOS7, I've defined a UISegmentedControl in the interface builder and use the following code to customize it:

```
 segconOptions.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
 segconOptions.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

 //[segconOptions setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 [segconOptions setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];  //temp change for graphics issue

 [segconOptions setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [segconOptions setAlpha:1.0];

 [segconOptions setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [segconOptions setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I was expecting the text to appear over the background images(white text over blue, red text over yellow). However, instead, have these large squares around the text. I changed the font color to blue for the non-selected cells to make the text readable in this screenshot:

[image: Undesired whiteboxes around text]

How do I display the button title text over my custom background image, without these white boxes around the text? I assume I'm missing something obvious, but I've been searching all day and keep coming up with nothing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think that the problem is because of some unusual thing you're doing to the segmented control. When I set the background image of a segmented control and set the titles of the segments, I don't get any white rectangle - see the attached screen shot.

[image]

I tried to imitate your code (note the rounded corners) but I couldn't get any white rectangle. Maybe the white rectangle is part of your `blue.png` image! (Note that you should be using a resizeable image here, by the way.)

Comment: That doesn't work either. The image appears in the middle of each segment with same white square around it. It wouldn't really be a viable workaround, anyway, since the setImage call subsequently hides the button text.

Comment: Okay, I've erased that answer and given a new one. As you can see from the screen shot, I don't get any white squares, so I have to think that you're causing them in some way.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that my expected behavior is indeed correct. After much experimentation, it turns out to be some problem with the background images I'm using. I replaced them with two new images, and it's working correctly now. >< Anyway, I'm marking your answer as correct since it put me on the right debugging path. Thanks!